# Plot multiple columns on bar graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsIR6.png)

Is there any way I can graph the mean larceny rate and the mean burglary rate on the same bar graph as separate bars?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

We can apply `barplot` from `base R` directly on the `colMeans` output

```
barplot(colMeans(df1[1:2], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, we get the `mean` of the columns needed with `summarise/across`, reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and get the plot with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    summarise(across(1:2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything()) %%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) + 
      geom_col()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that your scales in both variables are very different. So you can try a facet approach in order to see the magnitude across the axis otherwise you will see two extreme elements. The code would imply computing the means with `summarise_all()` reshape with `pivot_longer()` and then design the plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Burglary_Rate=c(918.8,863.2,770.4,728.8,741.8,747,741,730.3),
                 larceny_rate=runif(8,6900000,7000000))
#Code
df %>% summarise_all(.funs = mean,na.rm=T) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black')+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  ggtitle('Mean values')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        plot.title = element_text(face='bold',hjust=0.5),
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))
```

Output:

[image]

Where the axis tell you the real magnitude. Otherwise you would have:

```
#Code 2
df %>% summarise_all(.funs = mean,na.rm=T) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  ggtitle('Mean values')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        plot.title = element_text(face='bold',hjust=0.5),
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))
```

Output:

[image]